# Under what conditions could organisms using a magnetic field (magnetotrophs) as an energy source evolve?

Tags: biology

At the moment I am writing a scientifically based project in the genre of speculative biology dedicated to the description of unusual alien organisms, and in this case I was wondering under what conditions could organisms evolve that could use a magnetic field as a given source of energy for their body?

Comment: My bet is on “never”

Comment: What do mean by *"use a magnetic field as a given source of energy"*? A static magnetic field cannot provide any  energy, any more than a static gravitational field can. You can use it to *store* energy, and you can use it to convert mechanical energy into electric energy, or vice-versa; but you cannot extract energy from it. So you need a variable magnetic field. But then our real-world plants use an oscillating electro-magnetic field as their source of energy. You cannot really have an oscillating magnetic field without the electric field component, so that's that.

Comment: in other words, we will not be able to somehow get energy from the magnetic field of some planet or pulsar, just as ordinary plants get energy from sunlight through photosynthesis